# Why is it that it bootstrap when I try to spell a word in a different language with accent symbols it shows up wierd

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so im spelling a word in portuguese and instead of PROGRAMAÇÃO it comes out like  PROGRAMAÃ‡ÃƒO.. it seems it does not get the accent symbols correct.. anybody have an idea?

This is in a:

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">PROGRAMAÇÃO</a></li> <!--Here-->
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bootstrap issue.
Add `<meta charset="utf-8">` into the `<head>` section

Comment: You were rite, guess im so use to dreamweaver already having that part done every time that I forgot to add it in the bootstrap html.. Thanks ! much appreciated.